# Odd Custom Message Creation Behavior

Tags: ros, ubuntu, message, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I seem to be getting strange behaviors on the message generation of a simple message.  I'm using ros fuerte, on Ubuntu 12.04 with everything up to date.
I've made the following "simple.msg"

```
Header header
```

I generate it using rosmake, with rosbuild_genmsg() set.  When I try to import this message, using

```
 #include "msgTest/simple.h"
```

It fails giving me this error
`msgTest/simple.h:92:39: error: expected primary-expression before ‘==’ token`

I looked at the simple.h in (msg_gen/cpp/include/msgTest/simple.h) that was auto generated, and here is what seems to be causing the error.

```
template
struct Definition > {
  static const char* value() 
  {
    return "Header header
\n\
\n\
================================================================================\n\
MSG: std_msgs/Header\n\
# Standard metadata for higher-level stamped data types.\n\
# This is generally used to communicate timestamped data \n\
# in a particular coordinate frame.\n\
# \n\
# sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID \n\
uint32 seq\n\
#Two-integer timestamp that is expressed as:\n\
# * stamp.secs: seconds (stamp_secs) since epoch\n\
# * stamp.nsecs: nanoseconds since stamp_secs\n\
# time-handling sugar is provided by the client library\n\
time stamp\n\
#Frame this data is associated with\n\
# 0: no frame\n\
# 1: global frame\n\
string frame_id\n\
\n\
";
  }
```

Its seems like the newline character is being place on the next line as I expect it to be more like "Header header \n..."  Any help would be much appreciated, as some other files that I made behave as expected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56033/odd-custom-message-creation-behavior/) by [pyrobat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3219/pyrobat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using "std_msgs/Header" in your .msg file

---

Originally posted by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) with karma: 435 on 2013-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0